# Change ECB link title to a workflow link

Tags: sharepoint-designer, ecb-menu

I created a workflow and published it to a list.
The name of the workflow is Office Approval and its has to start manually.
All is good but i would like to change the name of the title of the link from "Workflow"
to Office Approval.
Any ideas how to change this?
Tried via sharepoint designer but no luck

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to get rid of/rename the standard link

But you can make your own link using SPD:

- Open the site in SharePoint designer
- Open the list in SharePoint designer
- Click "Custom Action" in the New group in the ribbon
- Select List Item Menu
- Enter Office Approval as Name
- If you want the link to automatically start the workflow Initiate Workflow as action and select your workflow
- If you want the link to go to the Workflow page as standard select Navigate to URL as action and enter `~site/_layouts/Workflow.aspx?ID={ItemId}&List={ListId}&Source={Source}`
- Select Image if you want
- Select Sequence to position your link: 0 at top, 899 just prior to Workflows, 900 next group, 2000 at end

Comment: Thanks for the response.But coming back to this when i select an image the image doesn't appear.Any ideas what i'm missing?